# Idioms (light design patterns) for coroutine bodies that are long?

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

Sometimes coroutine bodies (the block passed to a coroutine builder like `launch` or `async`) tends to grow unwieldy. They are the "entry point" of the coroutine (analogous to a `Runnable` with a `Thread`) and can grow like a `main()` function grows. What are some idioms around providers of coroutine bodies? For example, can a class be used to scope a coroutine body provider? Or maybe it's preferable to have free standing higher-order functions that return coroutine bodies? In other words, are there any `Builder` patterns for when coroutine bodys grow in scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A coroutine builder is just an entry point into the domain of coroutines. Within that domain you can freely call any `suspend fun`s as if they were blocking functions. So the pattern to use is the primary pattern of all structured programming since the invention of FORTRAN: function calls.

That, in a nutshell, is the beauty of coroutines: their non-blocking "magic" happens in the background while you code as usual.